# Removing duplicate value from list of javascript objects in react js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, javascript-objects

I have react project and in that have a javascript array of object similar to given below and in that object it has a value called `category`.

```
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "item": "760",
    "price": "$609.05",
    "category": "BMW"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "item": "Frontier",
    "price": "$317.89",
    "category": "Nissan"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "item": "Odyssey",
    "price": "$603.64",
    "category": "BMW"
  }]
```

Im mapping through the list and displaying the `category` as shown below.

```
{data.map(item => (<span>{item.category}</span>))}
```

Here, the `category` duplicates and display several times when there are several similar items. Considering the given `data` list, the `category` `BMW` display twice.

What I want is, even if there are multiple similar `categories`, I only want to display once. Is this possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Create a set as set only have unique data, you can use something like this, [...new Set(data.map(item => ("<span>" + item.category + "</span>")))]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be various ways to reach the desired result. I would do it with a [**`Set()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set?retiredLocale=it) and destructuring syntax:

```
{[...new Set(data.map(item => (<span>{item.category}</span>)))]}
```

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "item": "760",
  "price": "$609.05",
  "category": "BMW"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "item": "Frontier",
  "price": "$317.89",
  "category": "Nissan"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "item": "Odyssey",
  "price": "$603.64",
  "category": "BMW"
}]

const newData = [...new Set(data.map(item => ("<span>" + item.category + "</span>")))]

console.log(newData);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could add your categories into a `Set`

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "item": "760",
    "price": "$609.05",
    "category": "BMW"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "item": "Frontier",
    "price": "$317.89",
    "category": "Nissan"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "item": "Odyssey",
    "price": "$603.64",
    "category": "BMW"
  }]
  
let categories = new Set()
data.forEach(entry => {categories.add(entry.category) })
categories.forEach(cat => console.log(cat))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `{data.find(item => (<span>{item.category}</span>))}`. The `find()`  method returns the first element in the provided array that satisfies the provided testing function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **filter**

```
 let array=   data.filter((v,i,a)=>a.findIndex(v2=>(v2.category===v.category))===i)
```

and

```
{array.map(item => (<span>{item.category}</span>))}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    "id": 1,
    "item": "760",
    "price": "$609.05",
    "category": "BMW"
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "item": "Frontier",
    "price": "$317.89",
    "category": "Nissan"
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "item": "Odyssey",
    "price": "$603.64",
    "category": "BMW"
  }]
  
function getUniqueArrayBy(arr, key) {
   return [...new Map(arr.map(item => [item[key], item])).values()]
}
const filtered = getUniqueArrayBy(data, 'category');
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use native methods `.reduce` and `.map` of `Array` in chain.

```
const categories = data.reduce((acc, {category}) => {
  if (!acc.includes(category)) { // check if there's not such value in accumulator
    acc.push(category); // adding category
  }
  return acc; // returning value
}, []) // [] is an accumulator value
   .map(category => <span>{category}</span>); // iterating over result
```

Piece a cake.